# How to map "ñ" and "º" chars on .vimrc?

Tags: vim

Using a spanish keyboard layout like this one:

[image]
<sub>(source: [terena.org](https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-mua/test/img/kbd_spanish.gif))</sub>

I'm trying to map in my `.vimrc` the `ñ` to `:` in normal mode and the `º` in the upper left corner to `<esc>` in insert mode but it is not working. I've tried with `imap` and `inoremap` on my `.vimrc` like:

```
nnoremap ñ :
inoremap º <esc>
```

I've tried with Vim 7.4 both on Linux and Windows (gvim on Windows). The odd thing is that if I do the remaps in normal mode instead of in the `.vimrc` file, they work. It's like these chars are treated differently inside the normal mode command line, in fact after loading the `.vimrc` a `:nmap ñ` returns "No mapping found".

You can check my current `.vimrc` here: https://github.com/juanjux/My-Vim-dir/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: Both mappings work for me, even in the `.vimrc`. Are you sure your `vimrc` is correct? I couldn't find ñ in there. Anyway check the file is saved as utf8. (`:help fileencoding`)

Comment: By the way I'd recommend to try UK keyboard layout. After switching from the spanish one programming is twice easier :) Vim is 10 times easier :D

Comment: You do have put them after the `:set encoding=utf=8`, right?!

Comment: @DavidEG: yes, the encoding of my .vimrc file shows as utf-8[unix]. I've tried with the english layout but I'm too old to change already, this layout is pretty much hardwired on my brain :) that's why I'm remaping some keys of the spanish layout (had success n-mapping - to / but not with these).

Comment: @IngoKarkat yes, the `set encoding=utf-8` is pretty much at the top and I put these in the "SHORTCUTS" section much below. But you gave me an idea: I commented the `set encoding` line on my .vimrc, restarted Vim, added the mappings to my .vimrc, saved, uncommented the `set encoding` line, restarted vim and now it all works. Looks like Vim doesn't like its mappings for non-US keys to be in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

DavidEG gave me a hint that led me to the working solution.

1. Comment or remove any `set encoding=` lines in the `.vimrc` file
2. Restart Vim
3. Add the maps to your `.vimrc` file. Save.
4. Uncomment the `set encoding=` lines.

This worked for me on Linux and Windows.